# springframework controller from standalone java code

Tags: java, spring

We have Spring MVC application.  One module requires to call the Spring Controller from standalone java app.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Dead easy:

```
new java.net.URL("http://localhost:8080/path/to/your/controller").openStream();
```

Just like you would do it in the browser. If you want to call the Java code directly, do not publish your controllers. Instead, extract business logic and provide it as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It's a POJO, especially if you use Spring 3.x.   The newest versions don't even extend an interface or base class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it through its http interface as it's a Spring controller. You could use a clientside http request and use the response. I'm guessing the method you wish to call does not resolve to a view, if that's the case then just use something like the RestTemplate class that comes with Spring 3.

Not sure if it would be a good idea to call it directly as Spring MVC projects are usually hidden away inside servlet wars.